# Python Serial Communication Confusion

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port, wxpython, pyserial, serial-communication

I am developing a GUI application using wxPython and python. The output of the application is a string of GPS NMEA data every second from the USB port. Now when I use the application file(.exe file converted from .py file using pyinstaller) it works fine on the system with python compiler(i.e., it outputs the complete string from USB) but on other systems(without compiler) it sends only the first character of the string. Please guide how to rectify this issue.

```
  def Serial_port_setup(data_to_be_sent):
    try:
            serialPort = serial.Serial(port = COM_PORT, baudrate=Baud_Rate)#COM_PORT and BAUD_Rate are selected by user
            serialPort.close()
            serialPort.open()
            serialPort.write(data_to_be_sent) 

    except SerialException:                           
            Print_Debug_Data("No connection to the device could be established")#this function outputs the string on the GUI
```

Comment: how are you handling errors? if you call the program from a cmd prompt do you get any traceback? My first guess would be you're missing a module/package in the compiled version

Comment: No, I don't get any traceback or warning during compilation.

Comment: start the program from the command prompt and see if there's a traceback. Alternatively you could enclose all of your code with try/except and save any traceback to a log file

Comment: Yes, doing the same, handling all the exceptions, like IOError or Serial Exception, but still the issue persists. The data received after the transmission is incomplete.